# How to solve this type of exercises $\sqrt{x^6+x^5-2x^3+O(x^2)}$

Tags: asymptotics

I have a simulation test with this type of exercise, asymptotic expansion:

$$\sqrt{x^6+x^5-2x^3+O(x^2)}$$

with

$$ x\rightarrow \infty$$

I have studied the theory of Landau's symbols but I have no idea about how to solve.

Can someone please explain me how to do that?

Comment: Factor $x^6$ forcefully outside the radical sign.

Comment: So I have $x^3\sqrt{x^5-2x^3+O(x^2)}$ ?

Comment: No. By definition the square root of a value squared gives the value.

Comment: Sorry but I do not follow you $\sqrt{x^6} = x^3$ isn't it?

Comment: @ChristianGiupponi: You are mixing up addition and multiplication. $a\sqrt{b}=\sqrt{a^2b}$, whereas what you tried to do is $a\sqrt{b}=\sqrt{a^2+b}$.

Comment: Ok, thanks, now is much more clear :) Can you give me another hint to understand how to solve? Just the first comment isn't enough for me in this case

Answer (score 0):

Write
$$\sqrt{x^6+x^5-2x^3+O(x^2)}=$$
$$=\sqrt{x^6+x^5-2x^3}+\sqrt{x^6+x^5-2x^3+O(x^2)}-\sqrt{x^6+x^5-2x^3}=$$
$$=\sqrt{x^6+x^5-2x^3}+\frac{O(x^2)}{\sqrt{x^6+x^5-2x^3+O(x^2)}+\sqrt{x^6+x^5-2x^3}}.$$
But $\sqrt{x^6+x^5-2x^3+O(x^2)}+\sqrt{x^6+x^5-2x^3}\sim 2x^3$, hence
$$\frac{O(x^2)}{\sqrt{x^6+x^5-2x^3+O(x^2)}+\sqrt{x^6+x^5-2x^3}}=O(x^{-1})$$
thus
$$\sqrt{x^6+x^5-2x^3+O(x^2)}=\sqrt{x^6+x^5-2x^3}+O(x^{-1})$$

Comment: why did you do $\frac{O(x^2)}{\sqrt{x^6+x^5-2x^3+O(x^2)}+\sqrt{x^6+x^5-2x^3}}$

Comment: @ChristianGiupponi: He did it because it brought him closer to the final answer - he replaced subtraction between two similar terms, which by itself is difficult to evaluate, with a division between two terms with clear growth. To see that it's correct, try multiplying the denominator with the expression he's replacing.